# 'TypeError: dest.on is not a function' with this react setup - why?

Tags: reactjs, build, ecmascript-6, gulp

I am trying to get this simple site to work with React and Gulp, but am getting an error: "TypeError: dest.on is not a function" in the terminal. Not sure how this can be resolved? Any ideas? Thank you for the help here.

Gulp File:

```
// packages
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
    concat = require('concat');

// build all the JavaScript things
gulp.task('default', function() {
    var src = [
        './src/script/*.js',
        './src/components/*.jsx'
        ];
    return gulp.src(src)
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                .pipe(babel({
                    presets: [
                        'es2015',
                        'react'
                        ]
                    }))
                .pipe(concat('dw.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/script'));
});
```

Here is the error I see in the terminal:

```
$ gulp
[14:17:30] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[14:17:30] Using gulpfile ~/Dropbox/mashydesign/designSite/gulp test 3/gulpfile.babel.js
[14:17:30] Starting 'default'...
[14:17:30] 'default' errored after 18 ms
[14:17:30] TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/Users/MM2887/Dropbox/mashydesign/designSite/gulp test 3/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:557:8)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/MM2887/Dropbox/mashydesign/designSite/gulp test 3/gulpfile.babel.js:21:6)
    at module.exports (/Users/MM2887/Dropbox/mashydesign/designSite/gulp test 3/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/MM2887/Dropbox/mashydesign/designSite/gulp test 3/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/MM2887/Dropbox/mashydesign/designSite/gulp test 3/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/MM2887/Dropbox/mashydesign/designSite/gulp test 3/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11) /Users/MM2887/Dropbox/mashydesign/designSite/gulp test 3/node_modules/concat/index.js:17
        const fileList = files.map(f => path_1.join(folder, f));
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: Please include the full error message. Stack traces make a huge difference when debugging issues, even if they are sometimes hard to follow. The message alone is not enough much of the time.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Sorry about that. Added it in.

Comment: Did you mean for `concat` to be `gulp-concat`? Seems like you're using the wrong module.

Comment: The error output says `gulpfile.babel.js:21:6` so line 21 is the issue. I assume that is the `.pipe(concat('dw.js'))` line?